# cannot populate data in auto complete text field

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

```
              var data_names;
     jQuery.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: 'AutoCompleteHandler.php',
     data: {d_name: "d_name"},
     dataType: "html",
     success: function(data) {

      data_names=data;
        console.log(data);

     }

 });

$("#p_name").autocomplete({
    minLength: 2,
    source:data_names, 
    focus: function(event, ui) {
        $("#p_name").val(ui.item.label);
        return false;
    },
    select: function(event, ui) {


        return false;
    }
})
        .data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
    return $("<li>")
            .append("<a>" + item.label + "/" + item.p_gender + "/" + item.p_age + "</a>")
            .appendTo(ul);
};
```

i tried above code to populate my autocomplete box with data.but i get following error.when i print the json i get the expected json.but when i tried to attach it to autocomplete box.i get json array data with following error.

```
        [{"0":"kasun","p_name":"kasun","1":"Male","p_gender":"Male","2":"02-01-   1988","p_age":"02-01-1988","3":"880020110v","p_nic":"880020110v"}]
    Uncaught TypeError: Property 'source' of object [object Object] is not a function
```

Answer (score 0):

Not totally sure but I think if you add this it may help towards a sloution.

In this code change `data_names=data;` to `data_names = jQuery.parseJSON(data);` to convert the json string into a proper json object that autocomplete can handle properly.

```
var data_names;
jQuery.ajax(
     {
        type: "POST",
        url: 'AutoCompleteHandler.php',
        data: {d_name: "d_name"},
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(data) {
              //data_names=data;
              data_names = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
              console.log(data);
        }

});
```

EDIT: This is possibly why autocommit does not like the data you have passed it.

***From autocommit documentation:***

```
Array: An array can be used for local data. There are two supported formats:

    An array of strings: [ "Choice1", "Choice2" ]
    An array of objects with label and value properties: [ { label: "Choice1", value: "value1" }, ... ]
```

*When re-hydtrated your data it looks like this:*

```
Array
(
   [0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [0] => kasun
        [p_name] => kasun
        [1] => Male
        [p_gender] => Male
        [2] => 02-01-   1988
        [p_age] => 02-01-1988
        [3] => 880020110v
        [p_nic] => 880020110v
    )
)
```

*Thats not like either of the options*

So I assume autocommit has decided as its not like anything else I will assume its a function, but of course it not a function, its just an incorrectly formatted array, so it throws an exception.

As you seem to have picked the *[ { label: "Choice1", value: "value1" }, ... ]* method, intensionally or not, you need to change the PHP that creates this array so it generates the array in the correct format for autocommit to use.
So when it is passed back from the PHP it looks like this:

```
{"p_name":"kasun","p_gender":"Male","p_age":"02-01-1988","p_nic":"880020110v"}
```

Comment: @Dilshi Ok I checked out the manual http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source Your data does not seem to match anything the widget is expecting. The error mesage is basiccally saying I dont like the data you passed me in the `source` parameter. So its definitely something to do with how your data is being formatted by the call to `AutoCompleteHandler.php`

Comment: i used standard json encode method to pass data.so i think there is no error in my code.if i m wrong plz help me

Comment: @Dilshi I have added to the answer.

Comment: but when i print the data in console it prints {"p_name":"kasun","p_gender":"Male","p_age":"02-01-1988","p_nic":"880020110v"}.that means it get hte correct format